# angularjs ng-change function not fire poperly in html input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<input name="maxSalary" id="MaxSalary" type="number" min="0" class="form-control" ng-model="dp.maximumSalary" ng-change="minMaxSalaryComparision()" />
```

this is my html input. when I add a integer value, its work properly. but if I add 0000 ng-change only fire with first entered 0. this is my java script.

```
 $scope.minMaxSalaryComparision = function () {
        alert($scope.dp.maximumSalary);
    };
```

any idea?

Comment: thats because 0 and 00 and interpreted as same. So in dirty checking, the value is just still the same no matter how many zeros you add. You can use keypress event if you want to check for this scenario.

Comment: Actually it consider 0 and 00000 is same value. Because you select type is number. If you want to differentiate then you need to change type to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ng-keyup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup) or ng-keydown instead of ng-change

```
<input name="maxSalary" id="MaxSalary" type="number" min="0" class="form-control" ng-model="dp.maximumSalary" ng-keyup="minMaxSalaryComparision()" />
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("Demoapp",[])
.controller("Democtrl",function($scope){

 $scope.minMaxSalaryComparision = function () {
        alert($scope.dp.maximumSalary);
    };
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Demoapp" ng-controller="Democtrl">
 <input  min="0" class="form-control" ng-model="dp.maximumSalary" ng-keyup="minMaxSalaryComparision()" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ng change fires when you change the value of the ng model. since `0000` is equal to `0` ng change does not getting fired.

alternatively can use `ngKeyup` to fire this event when key released

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

 $scope.minMaxSalaryComparision = function () {
        alert($scope.dp.maximumSalary);
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input name="maxSalary" id="MaxSalary" type="number" min="0" class="form-control" ng-model="dp.maximumSalary" ng-keyup="minMaxSalaryComparision()" />

</div>
```